# How to tag multiple Docker Images at once

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-build

I have multiple `Dockerfile` files in my directory. I wrote a Bash script that iterates through that directory and builds all the images. But I don't know how to tag multiple docker images at once.

For example, I can build multiple images at once, but how to properly tag them?

```
for dockerfile in $files; do 
  docker build -f $dockerfile .;
done;
```

I was thinking of doing something like this, but it didn't work as it only tagged the latest image, not the rest of them.

```
for dockerfile in $files; do 
  docker build -f $dockerfile . -t $name:$tag; 
done;
```

As I'm doing this as a step in the Github actions workflow, I would provide the `$name` and the `$tag`. `$tag` would be something unique like timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not modifying `$name` nor `$tag` *within* the `for` loop the tag name will be the same for every Dockerfile. So `docker` will always use the same name to tag the images, untagging any previous images with the same name, i.e. the image built in the previous iteration.
This is why it looks like `docker` only tagging the last image.

You need to use a unique tag name in every iteration. To use the current timestamp you could do:

```sh
for dockerfile in $files; do
  tag="$(date +%s)"
  docker build -f $dockerfile . -t $name:$tag
done
```